# Join two tables from separate database

Tags: sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

How can i open db connection from stored procedure. is it possible ? is there any command to do this ?

I want use two db in one query but  ef return error for using two dbcontext. How can i join two different db's table anyway?

```
from a in dbContextArch.Archive
          left join dbContextMain.Envelope
          on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of doing it is by using a **[Synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187552.aspx)**, which will be mapped to the table on the other server. It can be created as below;

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[SYN_dbContextMain] FOR [dbContextMain].[dbo].[Envelope]
```

Then in your queries, all you need to do, is to use the synonym created instead of the server name;

```
from a in dbContextArch.Archive
left join SYN_dbContextMain
on ..
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response i want to ask one question. my two database is in different machine  is above code available for this situation ?

Comment: Yes, you just need to add the server name before your tablename, like `ServerName.dbContextMain.dbo.Envelope`

Comment: But second db is in diff machine. is second machine ip doesn't require for this ? If I don't understand what you say i am sorry